# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se vea el primer artículo en una sección, en vez de que aparezca el último en React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick, operador-ternario

Primero que todo perdón por la formulación de la pregunta pero aquí explico el problema que tengo:
Estoy utilizando React para mi portfolio, y tengo tres secciones donde se muestra el contenido con un operador ternario.
Lo primero que hice fue crear componentes de estado, por ejemplo:

```
    const handleContent = () => {
        setContent(!content);
        setContentJS(false);
        setContentR(false);
      };
```

Para cuando se haga click en un elemento, los demás aparezcan en falso (o sea, aparezcan cerrados)
Aquí tengo el onClick y el operador ternario:

```
    <section className="toggleCont" onClick={props.handleContent}>
              <p className="toggleP">HTML Projects</p>
              <img src={down} alt="arrow" className="arrow" />
            </section>
    
            <div className="containerWeb">
              {props.content && <Html />}
            </div>
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago click en los otros componentes que tengo, aparece el último articulo en vez del primero, osea, lo primero que se ve es el último articulo y tengo que hacer scroll hacia arriba para ver el primer artículo y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

El problema lo tengo cuando abro la sección.

Por ejemplo, en la primera sección dentro hay tres artículos), y cuando hago click se ve en orden, osea, se ve primero el primer artículo, luego el segundo etc... Pero cuando abro la segunda sección, que también contiene tres artículos, en vez de ver primero el primer artículo, se va directamente al tercer artículo y tengo que subir en la página para poder ver el primer artículo... No sé si me he explicado bien

¿Se os ocurre algo?
Os doy mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: Entonces tienes 3 `<section>`, y quieres mostrar solo uno, mientras los otros deben estár cerrados. Si pudieras elaborar un poco mas la pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Soy todavía muy novata en esto y no puedo hablarte tan técnicamente, lo siento :( Aún así muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! Un saludo!!

Comment: Sí, perdona por la formulación de la pregunta. Esa función se ejecuta correctamente, el problema lo tengo cuando abro la sección. Por ejemplo, en la primera sección dentro hay tres artículos), y cuando hago click se ve en orden, osea, se ve primero el primer artículo, luego el segundo etc... Pero cuando abro la segunda sección, que también contiene tres artículos, en vez de ver primero el primer artículo, se va directamente al tercer artículo y tengo que subir en la página para poder ver el primer artículo... No sé si me he explicado bien

Comment: Si ya se ve mas claro el objetivo, parece un problema que se puede manejar controlando la posición de los contenedores con CSS, no soy experto n CSS;  espero que algún colega de la comunidad nos pueda apoyar.